# Как применить функцию ко всем значениям колонки в pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть `DataFrame` с колонкой `FullName` состоящей из `LastName` и `FirstName`.

```
id|Sex   |FullName
-----------------------
1 |male  |Jonh Snow
2 |male  |Robert Boui
3 |female|Sara Konnor
4 |male  |Alan Miller
5 |female|Sara Konnor
```

Я хочу из колонки `FullName` получить только `FirstName`.
Для извлечения имени я написал функцию:

```
import re
def get_name(name):
    return re.findall(r'\w+', name)[0]
```

которая возвращает мне первое слово из строки.
Я нашел `apply` но похоже ее нельзя использовать для того, чтобы применить только к одному столбцу из всех.
Из документации:

> **axis** : {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0
>
> 0 or ‘index’: apply function to each column
>
> 1 or ‘columns’: apply function to each row

Как мне применить свою функцию к каждому значению столбца `FullName` моего  `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [22]: def get_first_word(s):
    ...:     return s.split(maxsplit=1)[0]
```

Чтобы применить функцию только к одному столбцу:

```
In [24]: df['FirstName'] = df['FullName'].apply(get_first_word)

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
   id     Sex     FullName FirstName
0   1    male    Jonh Snow      Jonh
1   2    male  Robert Boui    Robert
2   3  female  Sara Konnor      Sara
3   4    male  Alan Miller      Alan
4   5  female  Sara Konnor      Sara
```

Также можно воспользоваться готовыми векторизированными Pandas методами:

```
In [27]: df['FullName'].str.split(n=1).str[0]
Out[27]:
0      Jonh
1    Robert
2      Sara
3      Alan
4      Sara
Name: FullName, dtype: object

In [29]: df['FullName'].str.extract(r'(\w+)', expand=False)
Out[29]:
0      Jonh
1    Robert
2      Sara
3      Alan
4      Sara
Name: FullName, dtype: object
```

*иногда* при работе со строковыми данными `list comprehension` оказывается быстрее встроенных векторизированных функций.

Пример использования `list comprehension`:

```
In [36]: df['FirstName'] = [n.split(maxsplit=1)[0] for n in df['FullName']]

In [37]: df
Out[37]:
   id     Sex     FullName FirstName
0   1    male    Jonh Snow      Jonh
1   2    male  Robert Boui    Robert
2   3  female  Sara Konnor      Sara
3   4    male  Alan Miller      Alan
4   5  female  Sara Konnor      Sara
```

---

Замеры времени для DF с 50.000  строк:

```
In [39]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [40]: df.shape
Out[40]: (50000, 3)

In [41]: %timeit df['FullName'].apply(get_first_word)
26.3 ms ± 107 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [42]: %timeit df['FullName'].str.split(n=1).str[0]
44.4 ms ± 1.32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [43]: %timeit df['FullName'].str.extract(r'(\w+)', expand=False)
51.9 ms ± 2.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [44]: %timeit [n.split(maxsplit=1)[0] for n in df['FullName']]
20.6 ms ± 131 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

Замеры времени для DF с 500.000 строк:

```
In [45]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10, ignore_index=True)

In [46]: df.shape
Out[46]: (500000, 3)

In [47]: %timeit df['FullName'].apply(get_first_word)
266 ms ± 921 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [48]: %timeit df['FullName'].str.split(n=1).str[0]
381 ms ± 739 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [49]: %timeit df['FullName'].str.extract(r'(\w+)', expand=False)
512 ms ± 1.53 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [50]: %timeit [n.split(maxsplit=1)[0] for n in df['FullName']]
229 ms ± 11.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```